# WebMatrix - Count within a foreach loop

Tags: sql, razor, foreach, webmatrix

I have a foreach loop which displays all my propertys on my site.

Within that foreach loop, i want to perform a count on how many reviews each property has. I'm having trouble passing a variable to the loop though. Here's my code:

```
foreach(var row in queryResults){
var propertycount = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Property_Reviews WHERE PropertyID = @0", row.PropertyID);
var counter = propertycount.Count();
    <p>Property Name: @row.PropertyName
    <p>Number of Reviews: @counter
}
```

Any idea's where i am going wrong?

Currently, this code errors with

> Non-invocable member 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection.Count' cannot be used like a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the brackets after count, i.e.

```
propertycount.Count
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to make the query and then get "count" property

You can do directly a "SELECT COUNT":

```
var counter = db.Query("SELECT count(*) as counterField as myCountFROM Property_Reviews WHERE PropertyID = @0", row.PropertyID)[0].counterField;
<p>Number of Reviews: @counter </p>
```

or

```
var result = db.Query("SELECT count(*) as counterField as myCountFROM Property_Reviews WHERE PropertyID = @0", row.PropertyID)[0].counterField;

var counter = result[0].counterField;

<p>Number of Reviews: @counter </p>
```

Comment: i tried that first. The page doesn't error, but instead of the count returned, i returns "System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[System.Object]" in every foreach item?

Comment: try with var counter = db.Query("SELECT count(*) as myCount FROM Property_Reviews WHERE PropertyID = @0", row.PropertyID)[0].myCount;

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo, that has worked, and also makes my code a lot simpler. I'm just trying to figure out why it works lol